# Asp/C# - Insert into database treeview checked nodes

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a treeview, designed in the aspx page which has checkboxes with parent and child nodes. Here is the code of it:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" ShowCheckBoxes="All" runat="server" ImageSet="Simple" NodeIndent="10">

                <Nodes>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Αιμόφιλου γρίπης τύπου b (Hib)" Target ="_blank" Expanded="False">
                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Αιμόφιλου γρίπης τύπου b (Hib) - 1η δόση"  Target="_blank" />
                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Αιμόφιλου γρίπης τύπου b (Hib) - 2η δόση"  Target="_blank" />
                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Αιμόφιλου γρίπης τύπου b (Hib) - 3η δόση"  Target="_blank" />
                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Αιμόφιλου γρίπης τύπου b (Hib) - 4η δόση"  Target="_blank" />
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                     <asp:TreeNode Text="Ανεμευλογιάς (Var)" Target ="_blank" Expanded="False">
                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Ανεμευλογιάς (Var) - 1η δόση"  Target="_blank" />
                        <asp:TreeNode Text="Ανεμευλογιάς (Var) - 2η δόση"  Target="_blank" />
                    </asp:TreeNode>
                    <asp:TreeNode Text="Γρίπης (INFL)" />
                  </Nodes>
                <NodeStyle Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
                <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
                <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#DD5555" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />

            </asp:TreeView>
```

in codebehind I want to insert the checked nodes in the table "P_vaccines" seperated with comma. I tried this one but it has an error
 "column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. in asp.net". Could you tell me what can I do for the solution?

```
 protected void btn_vac_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<b>Seleted values of nodes:</b><br/>");
        foreach (TreeNode item in this.TreeView1.CheckedNodes)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            con.Open();
            str += "Insert into P_vaccines values ('" + item.Text + "'",")";
            com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write(item.Value + "<br/>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the count of your table fields? Your Table definition consists of more than one columns and you are trying to pass just **one** parameters in the *Insert* statement .

Comment: My table has 2 fields. The id primary key and another one with the names that I want to insert. i thought like that because the id is auto increment

Comment: Well are you sure that your `id` is auto increment?

Comment: @user2946329 yes i am sure... what could be the problem? maybe a totally different approach?